# Sticky QWidget to right screen border when hidden QWidget and adjustSize

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I'm trying to make a QWidget sticked to screen right border and who display / hide another QWidget on the left side. The goal is to have something like that at final:

```
----------------------------------
|   Rest of screen    |          |
|                     |  Dock    |
|                     |  QWdiget |
|                     |          |
|                     |   button |
|                     |          |
|                     |          |
----------------------------------
```

After clicked on button:

```
----------------------------------
|  Panel QWidget      |          |
|                     |  Dock    |
|                     |  QWdiget |
|                     |          |
|                     |   button |
|                     |          |
|                     |          |
----------------------------------
```

So far everything is fine, but as soon as I press the button, the QWidget "dock" moves and does not want to stay at the edge of the screen. If I try to put it back in the right place, it is not in the right place and give me something like this:

```
----------------------------------
|  Rest of screen     |          |
|  when Panel Qwidget | ---------| 
|  is hidden          | |  Dock  |
|                     | |QWdiget |
|                     | |        |
|                     | | button |
|                     | |        |
|                     | |        |
----------------------------------
```

Is there a way to accomplish what I want? Keep the QWidget Dock right without it moving and display the QWidget Panel just with the button to take the rest of the screen? I tried to "play" with the QSizePolicy, but without success.

Here is my sample code:

```
from PyQt5.Qt import QWidget, QApplication, QLabel, QHBoxLayout, QPushButton, QSizePolicy


class DockWidget(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super(DockWidget, self).__init__()
        self.button = QPushButton('Panel')

    def initialize(self):
        """

        :return:
        """

        layout = QHBoxLayout()
        self.setLayout(layout)

        label = QLabel('Dock')
        layout.addWidget(label)

        layout.addWidget(self.button)

class PanelWidget(QWidget):

    def initialize(self):
        """

        :return:
        """

        layout = QHBoxLayout()
        self.setLayout(layout)

        label = QLabel('Panel')
        layout.addWidget(label)

        # self.setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Expanding, QSizePolicy.Fixed)


class MainWidget(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWidget, self).__init__()
        self.panel = PanelWidget()
        self.dock = DockWidget()
        self.pos_x = 0

    def initialize(self):
        """

        :return:
        """

        layout = QHBoxLayout()
        self.setLayout(layout)

        self.panel.initialize()
        self.panel.hide()

        desktop = QApplication.desktop().availableGeometry()
        x_size = desktop.width() * 0.2
        y_size = desktop.height()

        pos_x = desktop.width() - self.width() * 0.5

        self.dock.setFixedSize(x_size, y_size)
        self.move(pos_x, 0)
        self.pos_x = pos_x

        self.dock.initialize()
        self.panel.resize(desktop.width() - x_size, desktop.height() - y_size)

        layout.addWidget(self.panel)
        layout.addWidget(self.dock)

        self.dock.button.clicked.connect(self.expand_panel)
        self.dock.show()

        self.setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Preferred, QSizePolicy.Preferred)

    def expand_panel(self):
        """

        :return:
        """

        if self.panel.isHidden():

            self.panel.show()
        else:
            # self.move(self.pos_x, 0)
            self.panel.hide()
            self.adjustSize()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    main = MainWidget()
    main.initialize()

    main.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to move and resize the main window, rather than the widgets it contains. Also. your current code does not take account of the window frame, which means it could end up being resized larger than the desktop, or being positioned partly off-screen.

If your application needs to work on X11 (i.e. most Linux systems), there are several difficulties to overcome in making this work properly (see [X11 peculiarities](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/application-windows.html#x11-peculiarities) in the Qt docs for more details). The main one is that X11 window-managers add the window-frame *asynchronously* after `show()` is called. This means there is no way to calculate the correct geometry at the point when you first create and initialise your window. Also, there is no guarantee that the frame geometry will be reported accurately if you need to query it later. So a little bit of hackery is required to work around these issues.

The script below is attempt to do this based on your original example. It works well on my system (Linux, with an Openbox window-manager), but there is every chance that it won't work the same on yours. A single-shot timer is used to re-adjust the geometry after the window is shown on screen - I used the shortest delay I could for this, but you may need to make it a little longer. This delay may produce a slight flicker when expanding the panel, but I think it is unavoidable.

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *

class DockWidget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(DockWidget, self).__init__()
        self.button = QPushButton('Panel')

    def initialize(self):
        layout = QHBoxLayout()
        self.setLayout(layout)
        label = QLabel('Dock')
        layout.addWidget(label)
        layout.addWidget(self.button)

class PanelWidget(QWidget):
    def initialize(self):
        layout = QHBoxLayout()
        self.setLayout(layout)
        label = QLabel('Panel')
        layout.addWidget(label)

class MainWidget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWidget, self).__init__()
        self.panel = PanelWidget()
        self.dock = DockWidget()

    def initialize(self):
        layout = QHBoxLayout()
        self.setLayout(layout)
        self.dock.initialize()
        self.panel.initialize()
        layout.addWidget(self.panel)
        layout.addWidget(self.dock)
        self.dock.button.clicked.connect(self.expand_panel)
        self.panel.hide()
        self.initializeGeometry(0.2)
        self.dock.setMaximumWidth(self.width())

    def initializeGeometry(self, proportion, adjust=True):
        desktop = QApplication.desktop().availableGeometry()
        width = int(desktop.width() * proportion)
        height = desktop.height()
        client = self.geometry()
        frame = self.frameGeometry()
        xoffset = frame.width() - client.width()
        yoffset = frame.height() - client.height()
        self.move(desktop.width() - width, 0)
        self.resize(width - xoffset, height - yoffset)
        self.show()
        if adjust:
            QTimer.singleShot(
                50, lambda: self.initializeGeometry(proportion, False))

    def expand_panel(self):
        if self.panel.isHidden():
            self.panel.show()
            self.initializeGeometry(1)
        else:
            self.panel.hide()
            self.initializeGeometry(0.2)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    main = MainWidget()
    main.initialize()
    app.exec_()
```

Comment: After some many tests, I think your answer is right. I've to manage with the window frame to adjust size under Ubuntu (or Linux in general). Thanks to pointing me on this.